# Detect or Suppress Action errors during script automation

Tags: error-handling, action, try-catch, photoshop-script

I've run into an issue with the automation of one of my Photoshop scripts where it can be completely halted by an error in a supporting action set.  The script does about 99% of the work, but the remaining 1% has to be done in an action due to the work being done (the work is NOT scriptable, or at least not efficient in the least to put to script).  The problem I'm running into is that, if there is an error in the layer name in the action, Photoshop pops up an alert about the issue, halting the whole process until I click the "Ok" button on said alert.

Is there any way to catch these errors (a simple try/catch on the action activation code doesn't work), or at least suppress the errors so they don't halt the entire process?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Correction on the error type; it's not an "Ok" alert, it's a "Continue/Stop" alert.  The message accompanying it is "The object "layer "layerName"" is not currently available".  This happens if the person creating the action failed to rename the layer before performing their work on it and halts the entire automation process until I click continue or stop.

Comment: Have you tried `displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO` ? One idea would be to convert the [action to a script](http://ps-scripts.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ps-scripts/xtools/apps/ActionToJavascript.jsx?revision=1.29) That way you could script a case for the named layer. Or another (convoluted) solution would be to run a script to check for incorrectly named layers before running the action. Or better still, have a script run the action with a try/catch statement.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, been busy with work.  The displayDialogs option doesn't work when the error is within the action processing and I can only catch the errors if they are action name related errors; once the action starts running, it no longer catches errors until the action finishes and the script continues.  Your action to a script is actually the best solution; you should post that as an answer so I can accept it. I did actually get that answer as a reply already over at the adobe.com scripting forums, but would be nice to mark it as correct here for any that don't use that forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the action to a script using [ActionToJavascript.jsx](http://ps-scripts.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ps-scripts/xtools/apps/). After which you can then modify the script to look out for errors - such as you mentioned with the layers not being named correctly.